# Find equations of two circles drawn through the origin which cut another circle orthogonally and touch a line

Tags: circles, analytic-geometry

Find equations of two circles which are drawn through the origin to cut the circle $$x^2+y^2-x+3y-1=0$$ orthogonally and to touch the line $$x+2y+1=0$$.

$$x^2+y^2-2ax-2by=0$$----(1) is the general equation and $$b=a+1/3$$----(2) is the locus of mid points of those circles. I plugged $$y=(-x-1)/2$$(tangent) to $$y$$ of (1) and (2) to the $$b$$ of (1). Thus

$$15x^2+(10-20a)x+(4a+4)$$

I need some advice on where to go from here.

Comment: I figured out few days ago that because line and circles touch, the quadratic's discriminant should be equal to zero. Therefore:  $$(10-20a)^2-60(4a+7)=0$$  $$=40a^2-64a-32=0$$.  solving this gives $$a=2$$ or $$a=-25$$. And value of $$b$$ can be found by the same way and I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two circles through origin touching the line $x+2y+1=0$ are fixed. They do not necessarily cut an arbitrarily positioned circle orthogonally.

Either graph/ rough sketch to convince yourself what possibility could exist for an orthogonal intersection.